# ColorSync framework missing on Sierra when building with Xcode 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

When building our macOS application on Sierra (10.12.6) with Xcode 9 (9A235), the application will not launch properly because of the ColorSync framework -- this can't be located by dyld:

```
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
  Referenced from: /Volumes/*/ColorSyncTest.app/Contents/MacOS/ColorSyncTest
  Reason: image not found
```

Given that ColorSync.framework in the 10.13 SDK resides directly at /System/Library/Frameworks, instead of being a child of ApplicationServices.framework as it used to be, the error makes sense...
We've tried linking explicitly (both strongly and weakly) to both ColorSync and ApplicationServices -- to no avail.

The question is -- how are people using ColorSync in Xcode 9 on anything earlier than 10.13?

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 2):

We've managed to fix the issue by changing the deployment target for the dynamic library which uses ColorSync - from 10.8 to 10.9. I don't know why this works exactly, if someone else does, please share.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look for answers to these sorts of problems are the  [Mac OS X Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/macOS_10_13_0.html). You can also check the [API Changes page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation?changes=latest_major).

It looks like you are building against the 10.13 SDK and running on 10.12, can you change your target [macOS Deployment Target] to 10.12 and see if the linkage clears up?

Comment: We had checked both the release notes and API changes before posting here -- we'd also posted on the Apple Dev Forum and filed a Radar.  Nothing changes after rebuilding with a different deployment target: same dyld error.  Anyways, we have customers on older systems, so the deployment target was already lower than 10.13.